# Accidental moving of root folder unable to log in

Tags: root

I was using 12.04 lts as a fileserver(using Samba to access it from windows client machines) for a large amount of documents, and used to add files to it regularly. Yesterday I goofed up, I copied a folder into server, but noticed that I needed to move a directory and few files out to another directory. I moved few files, but while moving the directory, I used the command `mv -t /` to my serving directory. 
This caused instantaneous crashing of my system and when I restarted, it failed to boot completely and got stuck while finding `bin/sh` while trying to execute the scripts.

Is there a way to recover it, although I have the backup of may be 95% documents in a external HD, I need the rest 5% too.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the boot options dialog and select the option that says "Boot to root shell" or something similar. That should drop you straight into a root shell, where you can attempt to repair the damage.

If that's also broken and you can't get a root shell, you may screwed.

Comment: Looks like I am screwed

Comment: You might try removing the HD and re-installing on a different HD, then you can connect and recover the data from the primary HD.